# rspec --only-failures error NoMethodError 'fully_formatted'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

I am attempting to set up rspec to run only failures with `rspec --only-failures`. When I do this I get this error

```
     block in fully_formatted_failed_examples': undefined method 'fully_formatted'
     for #
<RSpec::Core::Notifications::ExampleNotification:0x00007fce3766b108> (NoMethodError)
```

When I run `be rspec --only-failures` I get this error:

`bundler: failed to load command: rspec (/Users/mikeheft/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/rspec)`

I have `config.example_status_persistence_file_path = './spec/examples.txt'` set up in `spec_helper.rb`

When I check out the source code on GitHub, I can see the line it's erroring out on, but I don't see a way on my end to fix this as it's in the gem it looks like. I have also opened an issue on Github.

Comment: I once had different error only when using rspec with `--bisect`. Turned out to be `spring` fault. Do you use it? Try `spring stop` if so...

Comment: Still same errors after stopping spring :(